# Should I mention the real reasons why we are leaving the country?

Tags: job-change, applications

I am a Software Developer in a European Country and a father of two children.

Due to the dramatically increasing criminality and extremism in my country in the past two years my wife and I decided with a heavy heart to move to another country outside the EU for the good of our children. I don't want to go further into detail here nor do I want to start a political discussion.

Now I am asking myself if I should tell this reason to my future employer during the application process. On the one hand I would like to give a reasonable answer when the question comes up, why we are emigrating, but on the other hand I do not want to sound politically motivated nor do I want to sound paranoid.

What do you suggest?

Comment: Personally, always go positive. "I'm leaving because I want my children to experience living in another country," "I'm leaving to give my children the experience of living outside of the EU," etc. These are all essentially the reason you had given, but said with a positive spin :). Look on the bright side :D.

Comment: Meanwhile, although your reason is different, the same advice has been given many times on other duplicate questions. You can see this [duplicate one here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/46794/should-i-provide-my-boss-with-a-list-of-reasons-why-im-quitting?rq=1) which will also lead to three other duplicates in and of itself.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I know you said a different reasons, but the situations really are not comparable. One is generally more negative and the others is more positive than the other. The advice will change here compared to those other questions you linked.

Comment: Can you say which country do you live?

Answer (score 2):

I think the generally accepted answer to questions such as these in this situation regards to: Moving to a safer area for my children. Whether this means across town or between countries matters little.

Few will question such motives.

Comment: Saying a safer area for the children sounds like you're insulting  or shining negative connotations on the original area of living. I prefer what Teacher KSHuang said in their comment of: *"I'm leaving because I want my children to experience living in another country," "I'm leaving to give my children the experience of living outside of the EU"* as they are far more positive. Better to sound positive than negative

Comment: Perhaps. But a logical concern for safety, especially for children, is unlikely to be questioned or dismissed. It's also a common enough reason for moving. If nothing else, you're comparing your destination area positively.

Comment: It might cause suspicions to be raised if you state an EU country with a generally proven track record of safety and moving to a country that doesn't. They already feel that this move could be considered politically motivated and don't wish to discuss to that. Alluding to the conceived danger, when there isn't conceived to be any for the vast majority could lead to a tricky situation. Hence why it's better to leave that kind of thing out and just refer to another reason entirely.